# Is there any way to interchange images with clicked image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, image

Suppose, I have 3 images.

A, B and C.

A is main Image.

If I click on B, it become main image and A will be placed at old place of B.
Same Condition, Now B is main image and if I click on whether A or C, A or C can change with B.

Any solution? Javascript, jQuery or Angular 2 ?

Comment: Means I need Swapping images with each other on click.

Comment: can offer solution if you share the code snippet that you have tired

Comment: I have not created code yet, I am using Html only and placing two rows, In first main image and in 2nd other 2 images are placed. Please give me solution

Comment: [image1] <> image2 <> image 3.   If I click on anyone of them these can changed with image1..Suppose If I click on image 3.. It will become image3<> image 2<> image1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:
    http://jsfiddle.net/wdryt9zv/175/
Where the top square is the "main" square. Then just replace the squares with the `img` you want.